# How to interface a Raspberry Pi Pico to DMX / RDM

Tags: schematics, isolation, rs485, dmx512, raspberry-pi-pico

Years ago, I was looking at creating a stage DMX controller using AVR. Time moved on and the Raspberry Pi Pico has now been released. I'd like to revisit the project using a Raspberry Pi Pico, which has got me excited about hardware again. I come from a software background and am confident I can do that, but am not at all confident with hardware (although I find circuit design very interesting).

This is my first attempt, adapted from my AVR design which was in turn adapted from an open source project online. Does this look like it should work as far as electrical compatibility with DMX/ RDM?

[image: DMX Schematic]

I'm aware about galvanic isolation being required across the optoisolators and obviously haven't shown how the Pico is wired to anything other than the RS485 portion of my project. I've also switched out a MAX485 for a 3483 (shown as a part label) to keep it all at 3.3 V. It still shows in Fritzing as a 485...

Although I'm very excited about the possibility of working on this, it's purely hobby, I have no timescale and just want to learn, so any criticism is appreciated.

Comment: I skimmed your AVR/DMX/RDM schematic and concluded that the AVR interface is as simple as 3 GPIO/optocouplers at 3V3 logic level. So you just replace your Adruino with Pico and no wiring modification is needed. For the software part I think you can just program three GPIO pins using MicroPython (easy) or C/C++ (harder, but you already know Arduino C++, so no problem). Me too hobbyist and I have been playing with Rpi Pico and MicroPython for some 20 hours and very impressed so far. It is an ideal tool to enjoy learning, IF you don't have any schedule to meet. Happy Pico playing. Cheers.

Comment: Analog Devices and others have isolated 485 devices. Removes the need for optos. I usually put 10Ohm resistors in series with the 485 bus and transzorbs to protect the 485 chip.

Comment: Thanks @Kartman - I saw that Maxim have isolated chips too but the aim is to open source this and the isolated chip was about 5 times the cost of the separate components. *However* this is only a hobby project not mass production so I guess that doesn't matter. I'll take a look at AD.

Comment: Since this is the DMX controller, it does not need to be isolated, in fact it should by default be referenced to mains earth. Anyway, the isolation is not needed. If the RPi has an UART with hardware support for RS485 driver enable control, use it. The 6N137 has push-pull outputs so the pull-ups are not needed. The 6N137 typically uses 5V supply voltage, so that might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks @justme. I had another look at the DMX specification and although it allows for isolated Tx, it appears that grounded Tx is much more common, so that reduces some complexity! The original open source design could act in Tx or Rx mode so I guess that explains it.